# Add custom, local project to integration-distribution

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to add a custom project to the distribution. The project that I created via

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.6.0-SNAPSHOT

is (obviously) not available via the official nexus. I did not do any changes to this project.

I fired up `karaf` in `distribution` and tried to add the new project as a new repository via

> feature:repo-add mvn:org.opendaylight.flowlistener/features-flowlistener/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features

and received this error:

> Adding feature url mvn:org.opendaylight.flowlistener/features-flowlistener/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
>   Error executing command: Error resolving artifact org.opendaylight.flowlistener:features-flowlistener:xml:features:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: [Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.flowlistener:features-flowlistener:xml:features:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in opendaylight-snapshot (https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/)] : mvn:org.opendaylight.flowlistener/features-flowlistener/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features

Is it generally possible to add projects that only exist locally? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifact repositories are configured using `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` in Karaf. The configuration shipped in OpenDaylight only uses the Karaf system directory; it ignores the local Maven repository entirely.

To add your local Maven repository, you should edit the `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories` entry at the end of the file to include your Maven repository:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
    file:${karaf.home}/${karaf.default.repository}@id=system.repository, \
    file:${karaf.data}/kar@id=kar.repository@multi, \
    file:${user.home}/.m2/repository@snapshots@id=m2.repository
```

By the way, unless you intend to contribute your project to OpenDaylight, you should avoid using the `org.opendaylight` namespace.

Comment: This works, thanks for your help! How can I add my local project to an existing distribution as `l2switch/distribution`? I tried to add `flowlistener`to `l2switch/distribution/karaf/pom.xml`, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Karaf distribution uses the settings in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg  to resolve maven artifacts. You will have to tweak these settings (e.g. maven local repo) for the distribution to find your local project. There is some in-line documentation on how to edit this file:
https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/assemblies/features/base/src/main/resources/resources/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg